# AppSync validation error doesn't trigger error handler in response mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am working with AppSync and it seems that validation errors don't trigger the error catch in the response mapping template.
The attribute values contain an AWSPhone input. 
If I input a wrong format for AWSPhone, the error (as expected) is:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 17,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'input.company.phoneNumber' with value 'StringValue{value='+1-541-754-300'}' is not a valid 'AWSPhone' @ 'createProfile'"
    }
  ]
}
```

My request mapping template is like so:

```
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.client),
  },
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input),
}
```

My response mapping template:

```
#if($ctx.error)
  $util.error("Custom error response")
#end
  $util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

It's clear that an error does indeed happen but it doesn't trigger the case in my response template.
How do I go about returning a custom message for a validation error?
Is it even possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, it looks like your `PutItem` operation did succeed and returned the item that you put on the `$ctx.result` field. Then, when AppSync tried to coerce one of the fields on the output of your response mapping template into a AWSPhone it failed with the validation error you mentioned.

The `#if($ctx.error) $util.error("Custom error response")` will catch only DynamoDB errors. The GraphQL coercion from your result to the field output type happens **after** the template has evaluated.

One way to catch this would be to add validation into your request mapping template before saving it in DynamoDB or changing the value coming back from DynamoDB into the proper AWSPhone scalar format.